# Get class name of django model

Tags: django, django-models

I have a django model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
  [..]
```

and I want to have the model name as string: 'Book'. When I try to get it this way:

```
Book.__class__.__name__
```

it returns 'ModelBase'.

Any idea?

Answer (score 204, accepted):

Try `Book.__name__`.

Django models are derived from the `ModelBase`, which is the Metaclass for all models.

Answer (score 84):

As suggested by the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45320826/532471), you can use `str(Book._meta)`.

This question is quite old, but I found the following helpful (tested on Django 1.11, but might work on older...), as you may also have the same model name from multiple apps.

Assuming Book is in `my_app`:

```
print(Book._meta.object_name)
# Book

print(Book._meta.model_name)
# book

print(Book._meta.app_label)
# my_app
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for newer versions of Django.

Comment: You're correct @Bobort, it's working on Django version `2.2.3` too.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. This works for **both** the model/class itself and an instance of the model.

Answer (score 75):

Instead of doing `Book.__class__.__name__` on class itself, if you do it over a book object, then `book_object.__class__.__name__` will give you 'Book' (i.e the name of the model)

Comment: This one helped me in my case.  I merged 2 querysets that are of different models. In a loop I needed to get the class name of the object when I'm iterating.

Comment: Peter, how did you merge two querysets??  Or is the merged set just a list of model instances??  Thanks

Answer (score 8):

```
class Book(models.Model):
  [..]   
  def class_name(self):
    return self.__class__.__name__
```

With this way, whenever you called `book.class_name()` in python code (also in the template `{{book.class_name}}`) it will return class name which is 'Book'.

Answer (score 8):

I got class name by using,

```
str(Book._meta)

Book.__class__.__name__  -> this will give you the ModelBase
```

Comment: Thanks; `str(self.model._meta)` is what I was looking for; as for the other give me the parent class.

Comment: If you want something more implicit than a call to string, then you can get the same (tried on Django 1.11) with:
`Book._meta.object_name` or `Book._meta.model_name`. Then if you want the app name as well, that's accessible via `Book._meta.app_label`

Answer (score 6):

You could also retrieve the model name from the model's Meta class. This works on the model class itself as well as any instance of it:

```
# Model definition
class Book(models.Model):
    # fields...

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'book'
        verbose_name_plural = 'books'


# Get some model
book = Book.objects.first()

# Get the model name
book._meta.verbose_name
```

Setting `verbose_name` and `verbose_name_plural` is optional. Django will infer these values from the name of the model class (you may have noticed the use of those values in the admin site).

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#verbose-name