# How to get a name of the class from class declaration

Tags: python, django

I have a next model

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
     # fields
```

When I try to get `__class__` it returns 'ModelBase'.
What I actually need is to find a method of how to get a class name for `models.MyClass`.
Is it possible without having an instance of it?

Updated:
Sorry guys, I put it wrong, what I wanted to ask was a bit different. I am probably to tired.
This questions actually duplicates:
[Get class name of django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599524/get-class-name-of-django-model)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get class name of django model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599524/get-class-name-of-django-model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyClass.__name__` should return the name of the class as a string.

`.__name__` in general is the best way to get variables and functions names.

Answer (score 1):

Try `MyClass.__name__.`

Django models are derived from the ModelBase, which is the Metaclass for all models.