# Django - Creating a Custom Template Tag to show Model Name

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-custom-tags

I have a model:

```
class Survey(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

And in my template I want to show the name of the current Survey model:

```
<h1> {{survey.name |name}} </h1>
```

I'm using a custom template tag/filter to display that name; however, it is showing as 'str' instead of the name of the current Survey model.

Here is the filter code:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def name(value):
return value.__class__.__name__
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling the template tag with `<h1> {{survey.name |name}} </h1>` you are passing it the string associated with the model. As the field is a `CharField` it will return a string and therefore the name of the that class is `str`.

I believe what you are wanting it `<h1> {{survey|name}} </h1>` which will send the template tag the instance of `Survey` and therefore get the class name from that.

Comment: So I changed it to just {{survey|name}} and it is still outputting 'str' in the html. 

Do you think there is something wrong with the filter I wrote? Should it perhaps be returning something else?

Comment: I think it is coming down to the variable you are passing it. I have tested with the template tag and it worked. Can you please paste the code which adds `survey` to the context? e.g. in the view or a context processor

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the above answer...

Your filter is calling `__class__.__name__`, which I believe would return `str`

Try changing your filter to return `value.__name__`

[See this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599524/get-class-name-of-django-model)

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

- if you have defined verbose_name in meta then you can do:

  return (model-name)._meta.verbose_name
- otherwise you can do:

  return (model-name).**name**